# Artisteer css conflicting with my own css

Tags: html, css

I received an `Artisteer` made site template to work with, but later there was a change: my boss didn't liked some elements I had to place and now I have to add an additional menu. The problem is that I can't reproduce the same look with `Artisteer` and neither can use my own CSS made menu:

```css
#nav ul{
    background:#EE9966; 
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0); 
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px; 
}
```

For some reason the previous style is affected and the items inside  are bulleted like normal lists. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `list-style:none;` to your menu?